# Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...contentList.map...')

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar

I'm getting unhandled promise rejection type errors. Every time I clicked and get overall 4 different errors. They are:

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...contentList.map...')
Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Right side of assignment cannot be destructured
Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'node.nextSibling')
Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'vnode.component.subTree')
```

I checked every unhandled promise rejection errors from site and didn't find vuejs related.

My component:

```html
<template>
  <q-card>
    <q-card-section>
      <div>
        <span>F.I.Sh:</span>
        <span>{{ name }}</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>Tel:</span>
        <span>{{ phone }}</span>
      </div>
    </q-card-section>
    <q-separator color="grey"/>
    <div class="q-pa-md row justify-center">
      <div>
        <q-chat-message
          :name="time"
          :text="content"
        />
        <q-chat-message
          :name="answered"
          :text="content"
          sent
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </q-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Chat",
  props: {
    answered: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    },
    phone: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    },
    time: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    },
    content: {
      type: String,
      default: null
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Usage of component:

```html
<Chat
  v-if="show"
  :answered="answered"
  :name="name"
  :phone="phone"
  :time="time"
  :content="content"
/>
```

I want to change the variable `show` to appear the chat and give some data to Chat component. In order to do this I used click event and this function:

```js
showChat(appeal) {
  if (this.show === true) {
    this.show = false
    this.name = ""
    this.phone = ""
    this.time = ""
    this.answered = ""
    this.content = ""
  } else if (!appeal.isEmpty && this.show === false) {
    this.show = true
    this.name = appeal.name
    this.phone = appeal.phone
    this.time = appeal.time
    this.answered = appeal.answered
    this.content = appeal.content
  }
}
```

Usage of the function:

```html
<q-item
   v-for="appeal in appeals"
   clickable
   class="row justify-around"
   @click="showChat(appeal)"
>
```

And I also want to mention that I checked that appeal object is not empty and in the function it is assigning to variables. One more thing, the `contentList` variable mentioned above in the error is not in the code I wrote but it's from `node_modules` package. Please review this if possible and I'll be thankful to you.

Comment: Screenshots are forbidden, please edit your question with proper (highlighted) text snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer. The problem was `q-chat-message`'s `text` prop. Its accepted value data type should be an Array.

Comment: Thanks! In my case I was running `.toLocaleDateString()` on something that turned out to not be a date object, but a string. Added `new Date()` around the variable to solve the issue.